# Mail sending code works at local but not on server in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email

My mail sending code using google stmp in asp.net MVC works fine at local server but gives internal server error 500 at remote server  sage.arvixe.com

Here Is my Controller Code:

```
    string email = "**@**.com";
    string password = "***";

    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("my.smtp.server.com");

    mail.From = new MailAddress(email, "Company");
    mail.To.Add("something@gmail.com");
    mail.Subject = "Feedback";

    string body = "CompanyName " + data.CompanyName + "<br/> Contact Person Name " + data.ContactPersonName + "<br/> Designation " + data.Designation + "<br/> EmailID " + data.EmailID + "<br/> MobileCellNo " + data.MobileCellNo + "<br/> OfficePhoneNo " + data.OfficePhoneNo + "<br/> FaxNo " + data.FaxNo + "<br/> Address " + data.Address + "<br/> CityState " + data.CityState + "<br/> PostalCode " + data.PostalCode + "<br/> Country " + data.Country + "<br/> Description " + data.Description + "";
    mail.Body = body;
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    //SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    SmtpServer.Port =25;
    SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(email, password);
    //SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
    SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

Comment: Do you need to do something like allow the server's IP address in your mail server?

Comment: Add logs to your code. Internal server error message is not enough to rectify this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about that, but it seems that you have to enable SSL to use properly this google service.

Maybe you'll find some more help in

this tutorial : http://www.dustinhorne.com/post/Sending-Email-With-Google-Mail-and-ASPNET

or this topic : https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps/fg5RNrQhdFY

Answer (score 0):

hi try this code it is working

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Form(string receiverEmail, string subject,string message)

{
   try
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid) {
                var senderemail = new MailAddress("xxxxx@gmail.com", "Demo Mail");
                var receiveremail = new MailAddress(receiverEmail, "Receiver");

                var password = "xxxxx";
                var sub = subject;
                var body = message;

                var smtp = new SmtpClient {
                    Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                    Port = 587,
                    EnableSsl = true,
                    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(senderemail.Address, password)

                };

                using (var mess = new MailMessage(senderemail, receiveremail)
                {
                    Subject = subject,
                    Body = body
                })
                {
                    smtp.Send(mess);
                }

                return View();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception){
            ViewBag.Error = "There is some thing went Wrong";
        }
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.